# JavaScript - Creating an array of all the ids of elements with the same class name

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to create a function which takes all elements in my HTML with the same class, and returns an array of each element's id and logs it to console.  What is the best way to go about this in plain JavaScript - no jQuery. Code below:

```
function subTotal() {
var regular = document.getElementsByClassName("regular").id,
gourmet = document.getElementsByClassName("gourmet").id;

console.log(regular);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The ouput or the filtering using `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: What classes do you want to test. All classes ??

Comment: All the code above returns is 'undefined'.  Is document.getElementsByClassName("regular").id the correct code to take the id's of all elements with the class name "regular" and put them in an array?  I'm new to JavaScript.  Thanks

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an "array like" object. Not a single element. See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Do all of the elements have their own id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already got an array of elements you're interested in, now you've got to iterate through them, picking up the ids, thus:

```
var array = [];
var regular = document.getElementsByClassName("regular");
for(var i=0; i<regular.length; i++)
   array.push(regular[i].getAttribute('id'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Create an Array (call `Array.prototype.slice`) from the elements and map the element id's:

```
var regulars = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.regular'))
               .map(function (el) {return el.id || 'anonymous';});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working copy in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/8hrHU/)

Markup:

```
<div class="regular" id="div1"></div>
<div class="regular" id="div2"></div>
<div class="regular" id="div3"></div>
<div class="regular" id="div4"></div>
<div class="regular" id="div5"></div>
```

JS:

```
var regulars = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('regular'));
regulars.forEach(function(regular){
  console.log(regular.getAttribute('id'))
});
```